How does the pin configuration on this switch work?
Could someone explain how the pin layout works as there are 7 pins?


That symbol is plain confusing. Seems it is a SPDT ("single pole double throw")? But how one is supposed to tell from that gibberish symbol, I have no idea. Whoever made this need to redraw the damn thing, use standard symbols.

Look at this picture, symbol and footprint(EasyEDA) from lcsc


Pins 1 to 3 are switched by the lever, Pins 4 to 7 are not connected to the switch. They only provide mechanical strength, but it's good practice to ground them, if your casining is also grounded.

They are the prongs of the connector metal shell to solder it firmly to PCB, so that the mechanical stress is not on the smaller electrical conductor pins.
You can ground it or leave it floating like any piece of metal, nothing defines what you are supposed to do with it.
However, it might be beneficial to ground it, or it might be beneficial to leave it floating, if you need to make sure it is grounded or isolated for some reason (like it will connect to a metal case and cause a short circuit and be dangerous, if it is on an unisolated mains powered device).
